# WCF as a Service Reference in UWP with Security

Tags: c#, wcf, security, win-universal-app, windows-10

We add as a Service Reference a WCF project. When we configure the communication client without security just all works fine.

### Without security

```
<security mode="None" />
```

And now the .cs file on a UWP app without the security configuration.

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
client = new ServiceReference1Client(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:1234/ServiceReference1")));
```

This sentences with no security in .exe.config just works as in Windows 8.1

### Adding security to .exe.config

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
</security>
```

And now the .cs file on a UWP app with the same security configuration.

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
client = new ServiceReference1Client(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:1234/ServiceReference1")));
```

Running the application with security configuration thows this exception:

- **Exception:** `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`
- **Message:** `"SecureConnectionDuplexSession is not supported."`

And here is the StrackTrace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.FramingConnectionDuplexSession.CreateSession(FramingDuplexSessionChannel channel, StreamUpgradeProvider upgrade)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel..ctor(ChannelManagerBase factory, IConnectionOrientedTransportFactorySettings settings, EndpointAddress remoteAddresss, Uri via, Boolean exposeConnectionProperty)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel..ctor(ChannelManagerBase factory, IConnectionOrientedTransportChannelFactorySettings settings, EndpointAddress remoteAddresss, Uri via, IConnectionInitiator connectionInitiator, ConnectionPool connectionPool, Boolean exposeConnectionProperty, Boolean flowIdentity)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelFactory`1.OnCreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.InternalCreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.ServiceChannelFactoryOverDuplexSession.CreateInnerChannelBinder(EndpointAddress to, Uri via)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateServiceChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateChannel[TChannel](EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel()
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
Fooooooo(String jsonRequest)
Fooooooo.<Boooooo>d__0`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Fooooo.<Booooo>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Foooo.<Boooooo>d__12.MoveNext()
```

### Questions

- What can we do for support security connection between WCF as a Service Reference and UWP app.
- Is this currently supported?

### Edit 1

I see that with the security on .exe.config

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
</security>
```

The **client state is in Opened**, but the **client.InnerChannel** threw an exception of type `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`

As @glen-thomas said, I try this configuration:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
```

But in this case the **client state is in Faultet** and threw this exception

- **Exception:** `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException`
- **Message:** `"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory1[Fooo], cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."`

### Edit 2

On the [`dotnet\wcf`](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf) page of github, we can see that this is currently not suported.

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v1.0.0-rc1.md

Answer (score 1):

If the security of the connection is important but not who is connecting, try enabling transport security, but set the credential type to None. This will secure the connection but allow anonymous clients to connect.

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
```

Alternatively, you might be able to solve your problem by adding the **Enterprise Authentication** and **Private Networks(Client & Server)** capabilities to your UWP application.

Comment: Hi @glen-thomas, I try this configuration and get an exception in the first `await client.OpenAsync();` call. `glen-thomas` with this **Message: ** `"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory1[Fooo_ServiceReference1], cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."`.

Comment: I added Enterprise Authentication and Private Networks(Client & Server) but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Transport security mode of NetTcpBinding is currently not supported by uwp.You can use the **basicHttpBinding** instead of the NetTcpBinding. The WCF which uses the basicHttpBinding with the Windows Authentication can be consumed by the UWP.

Comment: Hi @sunteen, but with the `basicHttpBinding` could I connect to my service without connection? I mean, I don´t know that `basicHttpBinding` on localhost allows me to send request without connection. Is this right?

Comment: @dachibox, did you think using `basicHttpBinding` you client app no need to connect to your wcf service and can consume the wcf? That's not right. Of course need connect. If you still have new questions I recomend you to mark the answer help you and open new thread for new thing.

Comment: In Windows 8.1 we are adding an Service Reference with NetTcpBinding and was working in Security Transport mode. This service is running locally on each machine and works without connection. I see now that this in uwp is currently not supported. https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v1.0.0-rc1.md Thanks for all @sunteen.